# How do I change text color with replace on ionic2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

There are my codes:
I want to change just one word in sentence while do replace. But not working.

```
this.reg = new RegExp(this.q.answer,"gi");
this.word["sentence_" + this.user.getTargetLang()]
.replace( ' ' + this.reg + ' ',' <span style="color:' + this.color + ';">' $& '</span>'),
```